# jquery item.hasClass is not a function

Tags: jquery

why isn't it working?

```
$('.cupsGame-level').each((i, item) => {
    if (item.hasClass(`cupsGame-level-${this.gameCupsStats.level}`)) {
        item.addClass('passedLevel');
    }
})
```

im pretty sure i have jquery object instead of basic DOM el

Comment: "*im pretty sure i have jquery object instead of basic DOM object*" you don't. It's a normal element.

Comment: Have a look at the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/each/). You need to use `$(item).addClass(...)`

Comment: "*I'm pretty sure I have jquery object*" - a very quick bit of debugging would confirm/deny that to be 100% sure you *don't* have a jquery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` in your code is a basic DOM element, not the DOM object.

So you need to put it inside `$()` to make it DOM object and to make your code work:

```
$('.cupsGame-level').each((i, item) => {
   if ($(item).hasClass(`cupsGame-level-${this.gameCupsStats.level}`)) {
      $(item).addClass('passedLevel');
   }
})
```

Sample example:

```js
$('.cupsGame-level').each((i, item) => {
  /*for understanding purpose  
  if (i == 0) {
    console.log(item); //check output
    console.log($(item)); //check output
  }*/

  if ($(item).hasClass(`cupsGame-level-${i}`)) {
    $(item).addClass('passedLevel');
  }
});
```

```css
.passedLevel {
  background: darkgrey;
  height: 30px;
}

.passedLevel p {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cupsGame-level cupsGame-level-0">
  <p>This is first text</p>
</div>
<div class="cupsGame-level">
  <p>This is second text</p>
</div>
<div class="cupsGame-level cupsGame-level-2">
  <p>This is third text</p>
</div>
<div class="cupsGame-level">
  <p>This is fourth text</p>
</div>
<div class="cupsGame-level cupsGame-level-4">
  <p>This is fifth text</p>
</div>
```

Note: do `console.log(item);console.log($(item));` to see the difference. Added in my code snippet too.